# How to select all child elements with a specific class using the "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a navigation bar that allows a user to view a dropdown after hovering or clicking a link. Each link has a class called "nav_item". There is more than 1 dropdown menu; each one has a class called "dropdown". After hovering over "nav_item" the child element with a class called "dropdown" should be set to "display: block;".

Here's my nav bar code:

```html
<nav>
    <div id="nav_title">
        Learn Web Design
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Intro</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Learn</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <a href="#" class="nav_link">About</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The Author</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Support</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the jQuery code that is obviously syntactically incorrect:

```
$(".nav_item").click(function() {
    $(this.".dropdown").css("display", "block");
});
```

There's another method that is clearly incorrect in CSS:

```
.nav_item:hover {
    this.dropdown {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".nav_item").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown").css("display", "block");
});
```

To do something similar using hover:

```
$(".nav_item").hover(
    function(){ $(this).find('.dropdown').css('display', 'block'); },
    function(){ $(this).find('.dropdown').css('display', 'none'); }
);
```